# Android emulator itself restarting on showing dialog

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, emulation, android-10.0

I have created an emulator for Android10 on MacBook, It's working fine until not opening a dialog in an application, Once dialog get to appear on screen after few second Emulator get restarted with below fatal exception

```
libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 13879 (surfaceflinger), pid 13879 (surfaceflinger)
2021-03-04 19:01:59.453 A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_phone_x86/generic_x86:10/QPP6.190730.005.B1/5775370:userdebug/test-keys'
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2021-03-04 19:01:59+0530
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG: pid: 13879, tid: 13879, name: surfaceflinger  >>> /system/bin/surfaceflinger <<<
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG: uid: 1000
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'ubsan: add-overflow'
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 00003637  ecx 00003637  edx 00000006
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG:     edi e8b8733e  esi ffda89c0
2021-03-04 19:01:59.454 A/DEBUG:     ebp e93cfad0  esp ffda8968  eip e93cfad9
2021-03-04 19:01:59.477 A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-03-04 19:01:59.477 A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 00000ad9  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
2021-03-04 19:01:59.477 A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00092328  /apex/com.android.
```

Tried below things

1. Delete exiting and create a new emulator.
2. Cold reboot
3. Wipe Data
4. Change different configurations and system images.

Not working above solution, please someone suggest how to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: upgrade Android Emulator in Android sdk.

Comment: @ahmadbajwa i have already tried and updated Android SDK it's still not working.

Comment: the dialog works on a real device?  are you using any libraries or does this even happen with a 'Hello world!' type app?

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack it's working all real device, also with other emulator like android 9 or 8. it does not have any library.

Comment: Is it a problem of Mac?

Comment: are you running docker?

Comment: @CoolMind yes it's an issue on mac tested the same thing on a window it's working fine,

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack no, not using docker

Answer (score -1):

android intentionally kills the process because it thinks the UI thread is hung, so its an ANR right. for debugging purposes you can,

Go to Settings -> Developer options and check Show all ANRs.

This will show an App Not Responding dialog for apps running in the background. You can click the Wait button in the dialog to prevent the system from killing your process until the debugger attaches. Note that the dialog is opened automatically for apps running in the foreground. For background apps, you have to enable this option

Comment: it's not an ANR, it event crash with a sample app that shows the only dialog there are no other tasks.